# How to use Gmail.Users.Settings.ForwardingAddresses.create()?

Tags: javascript

How to use `Gmail.Users.Settings.ForwardingAddresses.create()`? 
If I do like this:

```
Gmail.Users.Settings.ForwardingAddresses.create('me', { 
  forwardingAddress: 'example@gmail.com',  
  verificationStatus: 'accepted'
});
```

I get: 'Parse error'.

Comment: Could you give some more info on the library and version you are using? As far as I have seen [here](http://google.github.io/google-api-nodejs-client/12.4.0/gmail.html#.gmail.users.settings.forwardingAddresses.create), it should be `gmail(v1).gmail.users.settings.forwardingAddresses.create(params, options, callback)` and it's meant to be used in node.js whereas your statement seems to fit the Java API.

Comment: I try use this method https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/forwardingAddresses/create and sow this link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail

Comment: Gmail.Users.Settings.forwardingAddresses.create('me', {'forwardingEmail': 'example@gmail.com'}); This result 'Parse error' in script.google.com. But in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/forwarding_settings I see the work example by the PYTHON 
address = { 'forwardingEmail': 'user2@example.com' }
result = gmail_service.users().settings().forwardingAddresses().\
    create(userId='me', body=address).execute()
What wrong with my method?